# Is it possible to create a timeout at suite level in testng for a test class rather than individual methods?

Tags: testng

I'm looking at a problem we have within testng. I would like to know if there is a way to specify a timeout at a test class level, rather than individual methods. I'm aware of "time-out" at suite xml level, but this then applies to each test method in each test class.

I would really to be able to specify a timeout that applies to the each class in an xml, so we can then look at improving these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout can be configured only in two ways.

1. At Suite level.
2. At each test method.

Essentially test classes in testng contains your testng methods which are your assertions of test conditions(in your case based on timeouts), so they are just normal java classes.

You can try keeping single test method per testng class and add timeout to that method or you can create a external method which will make the pass or fail decision based on the time taken for method execution.

Comment: Sadly I'm looking at making an existing system quicker (i.e killing the other tests in a class once we've hit a timeout) so splitting out single test method per class would be rather painful! Likewise, waiting for the test to finish doesn't help in this scenario either. Thank you for the advice though, looks like I'm going to have to try and create something custom!

Comment: Sure. No problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported out of the box. But TestNG does provide you with capabilities using which you should be able to build this on your own, with very little effort. [ I am using TestNG `7.0.0-beta7` for this, and this is the latest released version of TestNG at the time of posting this answer ]

1. You first need to create a custom annotation which can be used to define timeouts at class level.
2. You then build an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` which can read the value of this custom annotation from the declaring class of the test method, and if the annotation is present, then it would alter the `@Test` annotation's `timeout` attribute.

Here's a full fledged example that shows this in action.

Custom annotation looks like below:

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE})
public @interface Timeout {
  long inMs() default 0;
}
```

The test classes that consume the above custom annotation would look like below

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Timeout(inMs = 15)
public class TestClass1 {

  @Test
  public void sleepFor10Ms() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
  }

  @Test
  public void sleepFor20Ms() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(20);
  }
}
```

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Timeout(inMs = 5)
public class TestClass2 {

  @Test
  public void sleepFor10Ms() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
  }

  @Test
  public void sleepFor20Ms() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(20);
  }
}
```

The annotation transformer looks like below

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class TimeoutSetter implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(
      ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod == null) {
      return;
    }

    Timeout timeout = testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(Timeout.class);
    if (timeout == null) {
      return;
    }
    annotation.setTimeOut(timeout.inMs());
  }
}
```

Here's how the suite file looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TimeoutSetter"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass1"/>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Execution output

```
... TestNG 7.0.0-beta7 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...









org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass1.sleepFor20Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 15

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.unlock(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:652)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)






org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass2.sleepFor10Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 5

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.runOne(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:51)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.run(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)





org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass2.sleepFor20Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 5

    at sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetWaitStatus(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2303)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.transferForSignal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1674)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.doSignalAll(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1888)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signalAll(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.tryTerminate(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:716)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1014)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

PASSED: sleepFor10Ms
FAILED: sleepFor20Ms
org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass1.sleepFor20Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 15
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.unlock(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:652)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILED: sleepFor10Ms
org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass2.sleepFor10Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 5
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.runOne(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:51)
    at org.testng.internal.InvokeMethodRunnable.run(InvokeMethodRunnable.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILED: sleepFor20Ms
org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadTimeoutException: Method com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57307245.TestClass2.sleepFor20Ms() didn't finish within the time-out 5
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetWaitStatus(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2303)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.transferForSignal(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1674)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.doSignalAll(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1888)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.signalAll(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.tryTerminate(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:716)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1014)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


===============================================
    Test
    Tests run: 7, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 4, Passes: 1, Failures: 3, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: While this helps at the singular test level, this isn't quite what I was hoping for (although it's entirely possible I have set this up wrong). In your example of TestClass1, I'd expect sleepFor10Ms to pass (as it did) BUT then sleepFor20Ms to fail within 5ms (since 15ms-10 = 5 left for that test to run). Make sense? I effectively want to update the test timeout once every test has completed, and then fail the rest once we hit 0.

Comment: I don't think TestNG supports that usecase to the best of my knowledge

Comment: That's sadly what I wanted. Thanks for the help though!